# Old python version on linux, does it requires upgrade?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I keep getting messages when I use pip:

> Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained.
> Blockquote

what should I do? Ignore it? I've got python3 installed as well

Comment: You would have to update the `pip` as well, so something like this `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: Kind of depends on why it's installed and what it's being used for. If it's something the core part of the OS needs, there's not much you can do to get rid of it other than change your OS.

Comment: Is this the python 3 pip?  Odd that it would complain about 2.7.  If it’s the python 2.7 pip, quite the opposite: dont use it.  Try `which pip` and try to work out the reported location’s relationship to python versions.

Comment: there is a pip pip2 and pip2.7 so I guess there no pip3

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have downloaded python 3 but not pip3. The fix to this is very simple. `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` This command should install pip3 in your system. remember to use pip3 from now on to install packages for python 3. pip is for python 2. Also, don't delete python 2. It is a system requirement.